# Render array items within groups as separate JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array say arr chapters = ["C1", "C2", "C3,...."C10", "C11"] with 11 chapter titles. I am trying to render these inside `<ul>` as groups of max 5 items in each `<ul>`. So, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>C1</li>
    <li>C2</li>
    <li>C3</li>
    <li>C4</li>
    <li>C5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>C6</li>
    <li>C7</li>
    <li>C8</li>
    <li>C9</li>
    <li>C10</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>C11</li>
</ul>
```

I have passed on the array object to my component but I am having a hard time to figure out how to implement the conditional rendering part. This is inside (a bigger) render function:

```
<ul>
{data.chapters && data.chapters.map((chapter,index) => (
    <li>{chapter}</li>
    //??How to conditionally add </ul><ul> here to start grouping them into 5 items
))}
</ul>
```

I am thinking of using the index value to help me out identify the item number and conditionally render a closing `</ul><ul>` tag to close and open a new `<ul>` tag.

I am also thinking, maybe I should be putting the logic outside of the render() and pre-sort the items into arrays of 5 and then render them here.

Answer (score 0):

Return tags based on index.

For first element in the group return `<ul>` and for last return `</ul>`

```
<ul>
{data.chapters && data.chapters.map((chapter,index) => {
    if(index%5===1) return <ul><li>{chapter}</li>
    else if(index%5===0 || index+1===data.chapters.length) return <li>{chapter}</li></ul>
    else return <li>{chapter}</li>
})}
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't execute the else if condition as js code. It simple outputs it as text in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
{data.chapters && data.chapters.map((chapter,index) => {
    return (index+1) % 5 === 0 && <ul><li>{chapter}</li></ul>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    const courses = ["C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C11"];
    const getItems = function() {
        const lists = [];
        let listItems = [];
        for(let loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < courses.length; loopIndex++) {
            const nextIndex = (loopIndex + 1);
            listItems.push(<li>{ courses[loopIndex] }</li>);
            if(((nextIndex % 5) === 0) || nextIndex === courses.length) {
                lists.push(<ul>{ listItems }</ul>);
                listItems = [];
            }
        }
        return lists;
    };
```

And then you call `getItems` inside `render`:

```
render() {
    return (<>{ getItems() }</>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './card.css';
import _ from 'lodash';
class Chapters extends React.Component {
    state = {
        chunk: _.chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 5)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.chunk.map((part, index) => {
                    return <ul>
                        Group - {index}
                        {part.map((ch, i) => {
                            return <li>{ch}</li>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chapters;
```

The problem was to create dynamic iteration of `<ul> </ul>`.As the above person describing in the question.

So I have used lodash **chunk** function which will return two-dimensional array 
`const chunks = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], [11]];`

chunks[0] = `<ul> </ul>`
chunks[0] = `<ul> </ul>`
chunks[0] = `<ul> </ul>`

Comment: Hi there - great answer - might be even more helpful if you can add some explanation of why your code works compared to what they were trying to do before?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have added comments

Comment: @ChrisAlexander : while above answer implements the very same approach I have demonstrated in [my answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506175/11299053) I don't think introducing entire library just for the single item (*probably*) out of the toolbox is a good idea, especially for the cases when desired feature is easily polyfilled with a single line of code. So, I normally don't recommend to include another library if I'm not sure that user already uses one which is normally indicated by appropriate tag under the question.